# Override Activity animation in code

Tags: java, android, animation, android-activity

I want to override my default Activity animation, I know this can be done in xml.
But its important that its done by code, Because the position where it should be animated to is relative.

I tried to create a method but it did not work.
Can someone explain to me why I cant do `overridePendingTransition(slideLeft, slideRight);`

the slideLeft and slideRight are animation defined in code.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Android are you building in? The method `overridePendingAnimation(int, int)` did not get added until 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final conclusion, It Cant be done in code.

Comment: jajajajajajajaj